# Ryanair check-in luggage sizes

Tags: air-travel, luggage

Ryanair recently changed the rules regarding luggage and created a new category. A 10Kg luggage to check in.

I can't find the sizes though.

Does someone know the maximum dimensions for check in luggage? In particular the 10Kg option?

Comment: They're shown on the [relevant page on the Ryanair site](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage/new-bag-policy-effective-01st-november): 55 x 40 x 20 cm.

Comment: @jcaron +1 that's an answer ! Add it, ping me, and I'll upvote :)

Comment: You should make it an answer. I didn't find that page. The ones that I found only mentioned the cabin luggage. That one is very clear!

Comment: @jcaron can you add to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the ryanair website relevant section: [link](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/baggage/10-kg-check-in-bag)

you see in the picture that the dimensions are 55x40x20